# What do the Linux process files contain?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, memory, memory-management

So I'm back to toying with Linux, trying to find a good alternative to ptrace to create my own ReadProcessMemory function to replace the one I used to love on Windows. I'm trying to do some toying with the contents of the /proc/XXXX/ directory (XXXX being the process ID).

Currently I've made an application in Qt designer, with a basic GUI and a few distinctive strings held in the UI, so that hopefully it will be incredibly obvious when / if I do happen to find them in memory. The values I'm storing in this application are both in locally declared std::string variables, as well as being passed to the UI for display.

Can anyone advise of what the files each contain? Currently I'm in the maps file, and it appears to be a list of handles or references to physical memory addresses...? Here is a snippet:

```
7fffe137a000-7fffe137b000 r--p 00031000 08:01 4463612                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
7fffe137b000-7fffe137c000 rw-p 00032000 08:01 4463612                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0.0.0
7fffe137c000-7fffe1381000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 4462728                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
7fffe1381000-7fffe1580000 ---p 00005000 08:01 4462728                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
```

Not entirely sure what these libs are, but I'm assuming they are core components of the OS, and I'm accessing them via their physical address so that I can integrate properly through the Xfce frontend.

So, is there a list of the file contents somewhere? Or does anyone happen to know off the top of their heads exactly what is in the files? Or better yet, which file contains the values I'm looking for, stored in memory?

The reason I don't like ptrace is that is freezes the UI and workers of the game I'm trying to work with. I've been contemplating workarounds for a considerable time, just have never gotten around to trying to implement anything as yet, and currently I'm having to use Linux for my university studies, so why not try do this as well in my down time?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Why do you want an *alternative* to `ptrace`? Why do you think that your GUI strings are held in one of those libraries' memory areas? (libtxc is MESA texture compression and nouveau is a driver for NVIDIA, your strings aren't there for sure.)

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I will answer here then update the main post.

I'm looking for memory so I can effectively make a cheat for a game, so I need to know values from around a game client. In Windows ReadProcessMemory does this perfectly.

Comment: The unfortunate side effect of using ptrace is that it freezes the client both physically and functionally, meaning to make anything which will be successful will be very difficult and intensive. If I can directly access the processes memory (purely for the purpose of reading data from it) it should remove this annoyance completely, and reduce the amount of "ptrace" calls I have to make (though they would be calls to my own ReadProcessMemory).

Comment: The reason I think the strings are stored in my processes files is because I am declaring them as local variables, then passing them to the UI. That means they are stored both in the framework and hopefully locally in my exe. Unfortunately I don't "know" this, I just think it. Thanks

Comment: Most things in Linux have a manual page (man page) which you can access with the command "man thing", e.g. "man proc". Sometimes you may need to install a specific package to provide the documentation, e.g. "manpages-dev", "manpages-posix", "manpages-posix-dev". See "apt-cache search .-doc" (the '. is to stop it thinking -doc is an argument :)

Comment: Would `scanmem` serve your purposes?

Comment: @ninjalj - It probably would do but I'd rather do at least a large chunk of the leg work myself, since I'm not making anything to be released, more a personal project. I'll upload the sources of course if I make it work, but it's more of an adventure than a project...

Comment: @kfsone - Thanks for that information, I wasn't aware of the documentation so this will likely prove incredibly useful to me over the next few months!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) man page for details about `/proc/`.

The files (e.g. `/proc/$PID/maps`) under `/proc/` are generally pseudo-files (somehow like "pipes") which have an apparent 0 size and should only be read sequentially. They are not disk files, their content is synthesized by the kernel. So reading them is quick.

And `/proc/$PID/maps` describe the *virtual memory space* of process `$PID`. Read more about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). It is not directly related to physical RAM.
(You should not care about physical RAM, it is the business of the kernel).

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

PS. I don' think you should try to read some other process' memory without care. There are synchronization issues.

Comment: Out of interest, by the virtual address space, you mean where it is in physical memory? This looks like just the trick though... Thanks

You answered this question just before I asked it, I'll do some research to save ya'll the time I guess!

Comment: I'm not overly bothered by the physical RAM, I just have some interest in it for some reason. I've always been a little curious like that, wanting to know what happens next!

Answer (score 1):

I think that ReadProcessMemory() under Windows also stops the process whose memory is being read.

I don't think that there is a "less intrusive" way to read memory from a target process than ptrace() with the difference that ptrace() only reads 4 bytes at once.

However if I wanted to access the memory continuosly (e.g. a "bot" in a computer game) I'd do the following:

- Maybe it is necessary to do a PTRACE_ATTACH
- Stop the process
- Using ptrace to call open() and mmap() in the target process: I'd map a file containing special assembler code
- Using ptrace to run the special assembler code I have mapped
- Restore the registers of the process and continue regular execution
- PTRACE_DETACH if PTRACE_ATTACH was necessary

The assembler code in the file would contain the assembler equivalent of the following code:

- Create a thread whose code is also located in the file
- The thread would create a shared memory object and handle "commands" written to this shared memory object; the commands are basically requests for a memcpy()

Now you can map the shared memory section in another process and write a requst for a memcpy() to the shared memory section. The thread in the modified process would then copy the piece of memory you are interested in to the shared memory section or vice-versa. If you are also interested in modifying read-only memory of the target process the thread must also be able to perform mprotect() in addition to memcpy().

But be warned: Such a program is rather complex and not done in a day!

Comment: You've listed a very interesting technique. I believe this to be called injection amongst the botting community, and it is something I've explored a little on Windows. I'll likely do some research on it soon, thanks for the suggestion and for the conceptual explanation :)